# zsh: Can't set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH in ~/.zshenv to get ImageMagick working under MacOS Catalina

Tags: zsh, image-processing

Goal: [Install ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx) on my iMac 27" 2017 running Catalina 10.15.3 (install failed under Homebrew). Plenty of RAM & disk space.

Second line below doesn't execute, so echo $MAGICK_HOME yields expected results but echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH results in a nil value.

file ~/.zshenv:

```
export MAGICK_HOME="/usr/local/bin/ImageMagick-7.0.9/"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$MAGIC_HOME/lib/"
```

Comment: in the second line, did you mean '$MAGIC_HOME' instead '$MAGICK_HOME'? Not sure what the issue is, but if Homebrew failed, that suggests bigger issues.

Comment: TJ, the K is [correct](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx). ImageMagick is a long-established image processing library that does us the K as part of its branding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple typo!

The definition of the variable *DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH*  refers to the variable set in the previous line: *MAGICK_HOME*:

So add a `K` and the respective lines of .zshenv look like this then:

```
export MAGICK_HOME="/usr/local/bin/ImageMagick-7.0.9/"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/lib/"
```

Other source: [Mac OS X Binary Release](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx)

Comment: Aargh, you're absolutely right, klanomath! Thank you.

Comment: What's what I was trying to explain with my comment above :-)